# How much overhead does a Java Foreign Linker API call have?

Tags: java, performance

I was curious how much overhead there was in calling functions via [JEP 389: Foreign Linker API](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/389). I have searched around but I can't seem to find that kind of info. I was taking a look to see if it is realistic to wrap a c++ 3d math library that uses SIMD stuff with it. For this case the overhead must be very low since the operations themselves take little time.

By my estimations on my machine it takes 10 nanoseconds to call. This is certainly very impressive but that does not work out when the target only takes nanoseconds to run!

I don't have a ton of Java experience so I was wondering if I am missing out on some configuration things or just something obvious. I'm just trying to wrap something up for Clojure.

This is (roughly) how I got my numbers:

#### rtm.cpp

```
extern "C" {
    float inc_float(float f) {
        return f + 1.0f;
    }
}
```

#### Compiled with

```
clang -std=c++17 -O0 -shared -undefined dynamic_lookup -o librtm.so rtm.cpp
```

(also tested with `-Ofast`)

#### WrapperTest.java

```
import static jdk.incubator.foreign.CLinker.C_FLOAT;
import jdk.incubator.foreign.*;
import java.lang.invoke.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;

@Test public void testTonsOfSimpleCallsAlt() throws Throwable {
    var path = Path.of("/path/to/librtm.so");
    var libraryLookup = LibraryLookup.ofPath(path);
    var incFloatHandle = CLinker.getInstance().downcallHandle(
        libraryLookup.lookup("inc_float").get(),
        MethodType.methodType(float.class, float.class),
        FunctionDescriptor.of(C_FLOAT, C_FLOAT)
    );

    // warmup
    for (var i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
        float dummy = (float)incFloatHandle.invokeExact(1.0f);
    }

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    float total = 1.0f;
    int loops = 1024 * 1024 * 100;
    int ops = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < loops; ++i) {
        // The actual important call!
        total = (float)incFloatHandle.invokeExact(total);
        // nine more of the above line...
        total = total - 10.0f;
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    float nanos = (float)(endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("Time taken is ms: " + (nanos / 1000000.0f));
    System.out.println("Time taken per op in ns:" + (nanos / (float)loops / (float)ops));
}
```

#### JVM arguments

```
--add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign -Dforeign.restricted=permit
```

#### Java version

```
> java --version
openjdk 16 2021-03-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 16+36)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 16+36, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Looking in a profiler I am getting these sorts of call stacks around the call to the c++ function:

```
- WrapperTest.java:131 java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH.0x0000000800227000.invokeExact_MT(Object, float, Object) 991 1
  - LambdaForm$MH java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH.0x0000000800229c00.invoke(Object, float) 991 1
    - LambdaForm$MH java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH.0x000000080021d800.invoke(Object, float, long) 991 1
```

I have just run this via the IntelliJ test runner.

So is the overhead 10ns per call (machine dependent blah blah) or is there a way to get this running faster?

Comment: You might want to think about implament the calculations in java as the JIT usally does a pretty good job.

Comment: I was hoping to not write my own math operations! My ideal case would be to write a wrapper in c++ and then use the same wrapper in both clojure and clojurescript (via emscripten). I have just been using other libraries for now but I know things can run quite a bit faster. I have a particular scenario where I know I can hit the cpu cache a lot more if I have control over memory layout. But that all depends on the overhead of the interop. Apparently js->wasm calls are as fast as regular js function calls but I have not measured myself.

Comment: I just tried doing some basic vector stuff direct in Java using JEP 338: Vector API and things are already 3x faster or so than doing things regular java style. A vector4f add seems to take 0.4 ns which is nice.

Comment: hey @sh54, did you tryed to compare with JavaCritical_ JNI method invocation? It skips a lot of checks, so faster than general Java_ JNI. For my current project I tried with Foreign Linker API, it seems faster for simple method, but overall I feel (ie not measured) that JavaCritical_ gives me more relayable performance gain. For some reason I feel like Foreign API is not that good. I probably need to look into sources of invokeExact, to check. Also warning about incubator API is annoying. I am interested that you think about of JavaCritical

Answer (score 0):

I was really curious about this as well, so I wrote a quick benchmark to see how it compares to JNA as well as shared memory.

The results and code are here :

https://github.com/TwoClocks/benchmark_java_foreign_functions

I got around 25ns on this particular machine, which to me seems pretty good. Calling a C++ virtual function in C++ is 5-10ns-ish? Pretty good calling native code from the JVM (at least I think so). JNA comes in around 700ns. JNI might be a bit faster, but still far slower than the new foreign function stuff.